# OpenGL 3.2+ Drawing Cubes around existing vertices

Tags: c++, opengl

So I have a cool program that renders a pretty cube in the centre of the screen.

I'm trying to now create a tiny cube on each corner of the existing cube (so 8 tiny cubes), centred on each of the existing cubes corners (or vertices).

I'm assuming an efficient way to implement this would be with a loop of some kind, to minimise the amount of code.

My query is, how does this affect the VAO/VBO's? Even in a loop, would each one need it's own buffer or could they all be sent at the same time...

Secondly, if it can be done, what would the structure of this loop be like, in terms of focusing on separate vertices given that each vertex has different coordinates...

Comment: You should have a matrix that transforms from object coordinates to world coordinates.  You can modify that matrix for each cube to get it to draw at a separate location in the world.

Comment: Geometry shader, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vaughn Cato said, each object (using the same VBOs) can simply be drawn at different locations in world space, so you do not need to define separate VBO's for each object.

To complete this task, you simply need a loop to modify the given matrix before each one is rendered to the screen to change the origins of where each cube is drawn.